# Why to use Jenkins with RTC for Continuous Integration

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, rtc

I'm trying to convince my Configuration Manager to use Jenkins with RTC (witch we already use for Source Control, manual builds and many other things), as my boss asked.

**I'd like to know why to use the Jenkins with RTC. I know RTC can do Continuous Integration, but what Jenkins can add to it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTC doesn't have a build engine in itself. It has a build engine toolkit which abstract the actual build engine (BuildForge, Hudson, Jenkins, ...)

If you want to do continuous integration from RTC, you need a build engine.
The official one is IBM BuildForge (not free).
Since RTC4, Jenkins (free) is also officially supported, with an [RTC plugin for Jenkins to install on the Jenkins side](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Rational+Team+Concert+Plugin) (as well as the [Build System Toolkit](https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/5.0.2/RTC-BuildSystem-Toolkit-repo-5.0.2.zip) in the [RTC downloads](https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/5.0.2?p=allDownloads))

What Jenkins can add is:

- a greater familiarity with the tool
- a great list of plugins
- the possibility to experiment locally (even without RTC)
- a good connectivity with other source control tools (SVN, Git) in addition of Jazz RTC.